# Using onClick with jQuery POST not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, function, post

First of all, I'm trying to use an HTML element (button) to, onClick, perform a JavaScript function I have. The function is called Unban(player) which "unbans" a player from something I'm working on.

The element looks like this,

```
<button name="button" id="button" onclick="Unban('somebody')"/>
```

And the JavaScript looks like this:

```
function Unban(player){
    if (confirm("Are you sure you want to remove the ban on " + player + "?")){
        $.post("actions/unban.php",{Player:player},function(result){
            if (result.contains("Error:"){
                alert(result);
            }

            else{
               alert("You have unbanned " + player + "!");
            }
});

    }

}
```

The problem is: Nothing happens at all when I call upon the Unban(player) function. I've done a bit of tests and it runs properly without the $.post, so it must be something related to it.

The PHP file works fine and is functional. It is also properly referenced in $.post.

Comment: Are you sure you have jQuery sourced? Are you getting any console error messages?

Comment: Also, slightly OT, but its best to separate your javascript... instead of the `onclick`, you could have a descriptive id such as `unbanButton`, then bind your code to a click event on that button id.

Answer (score 3):

There is a syntax error. A `)` is missing here

```
if (result.contains("Error:")){
                alert(result);
 }
```